# geoFire.setLocation is crashing -Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, kotlin

I'm working on maps along with GeoFire. While trying to upload my geo location to firebase using:

```
initGeoFire.setLocation(currentUser, GeoLocation(mMap.cameraPosition.target.latitude, mMap.cameraPosition.target.longitude))
```

the app crashed giving the error:

```
GeoFire.setLocation - No virtual method setValue(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/firebase/tasks/Task; in class Lcom/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference'
```

Please help me resolving this issue..

Comment: do you have proguard on your app ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the way GeoFire declares `firebase-database` dependency. Versions after 2.1.2 use following version declaration (the latest 2.3.1, for instance): `<version>12.0.1</version>`. For the given version of the `firebase-database` setValue method is resolved into `setValue(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/firebase/tasks/Task;`. The actual method signature for the `firebase-database` dependency in my project (I use the latest 16.0.4) is `setValue(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task;`. Note, that the return type is different, that's the reason of the `NoSuchMethodError`.

The same problem exists for `removeLocation()` with single parameter as well. The quick fix is to use `setLocation()/removeLocation()` with an additional listener param - those method would be resolved correctly.

Comment: Nice answer. Work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do have proguard in your app maybe you should add this rule so the method is not obfuscated

```
-dontwarn com.firebase.**
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep interface com.firebase.** { *; }
```